# Upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade

When I ran the upgrade process from the software centre I got an error message saying I need to install linux-headers-3.13.0-101 which it apparently couldn't find. How do I do this?

Bob Thomson
Ottawa Canada

Comment: Make sure 14.04 is fully upgraded: Do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, reboot and try again. If any error please edit your question and add the full error message.

Comment: I did that. Thanks for the tip. This is the error message I got after running the above apt-get update command.

Comment: I can't seem to send this reply.

Comment: This is not a forum. Please edit your question with any relevant information. Do not use comments for that.

Answer (score 0):

Might find the answer here [Error message in upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863683/error-message-in-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04) sounds like they're having a similar problem. Error message is the same.