# Error message in upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade

I entered the following command as suggested, and below that is the error message I got.

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-3.13.0-101 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How do I reinstall this package?

Bob Thomson
Ottawa, Canada

Comment: Is that before or after the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04? What's the output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic`?

Answer (score 2):

To do the distribution upgrade, the command you want is:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The error you are getting is most likely due to the package it's referencing being in a bad state. There are several ways around this, however since you are upgrading my recommendation would be to first remove the package:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-headers
```

If this doesn't work you may need to play hardball:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-headers
```

Once you get that package removed, you'll be able to continue normally.

On the off chance that the above commands don't work, take a look at the answers here [How to remove package in bad state, software center freezes, no synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122699/how-to-remove-package-in-bad-state-software-center-freezes-no-synaptic) Even though you are not having issues with Synaptic, it shows you how to handle the bad package that's causing your error.